# Did these trades cause a wash sale?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, wash-sale

I bought and then sold a stock for a gain on April 15th.

I bought the same stock again last week and I am going to sell it for a loss.

Is this a wash sale?   This is USA.

Comment: What country's tax laws are you asking about? Please add a country tag.

Answer (score 1):

When you sell the current position for a loss, it will not be a wash sale.  You will be able to deduct the loss.

However, should you buy a replacement position (option or shares) within the next 30 days, it will become a wash sale violation and you will have to defer the loss and adjust the cost basis of the new position.